# String value to image in android

Tags: android

I have a problem which is to convert image from String. That String is returned from PHP , not from drawable folder. My coding is not working well. Here is my code.

```
picturePath = jArray.getString("photo");
             cursor.close();
             Bitmap bm = ShrinkBitmap(picturePath, 300, 300);
             Bitmap resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 100, 100, true);
             img_Photo.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);
```

Please, Guide me some ways.

Comment: why do you want to convert image from string. If you have php server, you just send image path like http ://xxx.png to android and display it

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799290/convert-string-text-to-bitmap

Comment: what does the string represent? Is that an url to the image or is it the image itself (coded in Base64)?

Comment: @henry4343 Now, I have to change this image. PHP return the String like that ("User_Photo/828220944.png"). Use that String, I have to on ImageButton as an image. So, I think you got it.

Comment: @blackbelt It is image itself.

Comment: I think this string is image name stored in `User_Photo` folder on your server. Append the rest of address of your server and you got the image. Download it and show

Comment: @Vishwas Sharma Can you teach me some good ways... :)

Comment: You'll have to get the rest of the web url to your server and then append `User_Photo/828220944.png` to get the image. First check on you computer browser if it shows you the image with whole url. If it does, I can give you the code to download image.

Comment: @Halo check this for decoding image (in base 64 string) to bitmap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945194/android-decode-string-base-64-to-bitmap